# Qt Drag and Drop Mime Data rejection

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qstandarditemmodel

I have a subclass of `QStandardItemModel` in which I have drag and drop working quite nicely. I store my data (pointers to classes) in a subclass of `QStandardItem`.
The classes stored in my standarditem all inherit from the same class, and I wish to enable collections of each subclass through dropping onto a collection type object.

```
E.g

--Apples
  --braeburn
  --golden delicious
--Oranges
--Meat
  --pork
  --lamb
  --beef
```

So I can drag different types of apple underneath Apples, different meats under "Meat", etc. I do this by examining the type of both the target and the dropped item in my version of `dropMimeData` (i.e. get the stored class from my standardItem, check its type).

My problem is when I reject an item by returning false, the item is gone from the tree. Is there a way to get the original location of the dropped item, so I can put it back?

Comment: You need to implement `canDropMimeData`.

Comment: I'm on qt 4.7, from what I understand canDropMimeData isn't properly working in 5.3